# Constraint Layout Centre Text Position with End Reference to Other Widget

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a dialog widget with navigation bar contains title and close button. I want to put the title in centre of the device, and put the close button in the end of layout. However when the title is long, then it will overlap with the close button. Here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Close" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any workaround to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to center text, you would constrain the start and end of the text to the end point of the centering region. In this case, since the text should be centered on the screen, you would attach the start to the parent start and the end to the parent end. This works unless the centered text exceeds the empty center region and overlaps the "Close" *TextView*. Unfortunately, there is no way to make these constraints and tell the centered view to avoid overlapping the *TextView* on the right.

To make it work, I would introduce another *TextView* that is a duplicate of the "Close" *TextView*, make it invisible and attached to the top and start of the parent. This will create a region between the two *TextViews* where the text can be centered. To ensure that the text does not overlap the end *TextView*, specify `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` on the centered view. Something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is some very long text that should stretch across the device and ellipsize."
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="306dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="62dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

which will show in the designer like this for long text:

[image]

and like the following for short text:

[image]

There are other ways to do this that would involve some coding, but this is an XML-only solution which, IMO, is preferable.